# ORA-00904: ORDER BY with UNION ALL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm creating a flat file with header. I'm getting an ORA-00904 error, which I think is because of the headers I created that does not have the field 'employee_name' (am I correct with that assumption?). 
If yes, how can I can I sort my query without the headers?

The error I get:

```
    ORA-00904: "employee_id":invalid identifier
```

My code:

```
    select 'FILENAME' as filerec from dual
    UNION ALL
    select 'FILEDATE: ' || to_char(sysdate,'mm/dd/yyyy) as filerec from dual
    UNION ALL
    select employee_id || emloyee_name from employee_database as filerec
    order by employee_id;
```

This is the output I want produce:

```
    FILENAME
    FILEDATE: 02/27/2015
    200125Ruth Chan
    200126Dan Gonzales
    200135Lisa Mayoral
```

Comment: The ORDER BY goes for the whole UNION ALL!

Comment: employee_id  is valid column name?? instead of name you can use column number(1,2 ,3..)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **SQL**, you cannot name the columns in **ORDER BY** with a **composite statement**, you have to use **column position**.

Or,

**Project the columns explicitly**.

In your case, since you have concatenated the columns, you cannot project them explicitly, also, column position would not be of any sense. You could therefore play a small trick. Add a pseudo column, with required values to the rows you want to be sorted first, and then use  **NULL** value in the pseudo column for which you want the sorting after the first column. So that, the NULLs are always placed in the end of the sort.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT filerec FROM (
  2      SELECT 'FILENAME' AS filerec, 1 col FROM dual
  3      UNION ALL
  4      SELECT 'FILEDATE: ' || to_char(SYSDATE,'mm/dd/yyyy') as filerec, 2 col FROM dual
  5      UNION ALL
  6      SELECT empno || ename AS filerec, NULL col FROM emp
  7      ORDER BY 2,1
  8  );

FILEREC
--------------------------------------------------
FILENAME
FILEDATE: 02/27/2015
7369SMITH
7499ALLEN
7521WARD
7566JONES
7654MARTIN
7698BLAKE
7782CLARK
7788SCOTT
7839KING
7844TURNER
7876ADAMS
7900JAMES
7902FORD
7934MILLER

16 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: A follow question. How can I write a trailer record with the total count of the details:

Answer (score 1):

Try order by column position number instead of column name

```
select 'FILENAME' as filerec from dual
UNION ALL
select 'FILEDATE: ' || to_char(sysdate,'mm/dd/yyyy) as filerec from dual
UNION ALL
select employee_id || emloyee_name from employee_database as filerec
order by 1;
```

or use alias

```
select 'FILENAME' as filerec from dual
UNION ALL
select 'FILEDATE: ' || to_char(sysdate,'mm/dd/yyyy) as filerec from dual
UNION ALL
select employee_id || emloyee_name as filerec from employee_database 
order by filerec;
```

Comment: It's possible that OP wants the result in select-order first, and only the last select in employee_id order.

Comment: @jarlh, I think it's more then possible; OP said the first 2 unions are headers.

Comment: UNION merge the complete result and order the complete result. No detailed order is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the last part of the `UNION` in brackets will probably do the trick:

```
select 'FILENAME' as filerec from dual
UNION ALL
select 'FILEDATE: ' || to_char(sysdate,'mm/dd/yyyy) as filerec from dual
UNION ALL
(select employee_id || emloyee_name from employee_database as filerec
    order by employee_id);
```

Edit: Since there is no inherent order, an even better way would be this:

```
select 'FILENAME' as filerec from dual
, 1 sortorder    
UNION ALL
select 'FILEDATE: ' || to_char(sysdate,'mm/dd/yyyy) as filerec from dual
, 2 sortorder
UNION ALL
select employee_id || emloyee_name from employee_database as filerec
, 3 sortorder
ORDER BY sortorder, filerec;
```

You may need to put this in a subquery, cause you probably don't want to select the attribute sortorder.